# Doubt in the reciprocity relation of partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, monotone-functions

Suppose we have a function $U(S,V)$ and $\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\Big|_V=T$
So we can say that $T=T(S,V)\tag{1}$
If $\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\Big|_V>0$, that means $U$ is one-one with respect to $S$ and $S(U,V)$ exists.

Also we have from the exact differential of $S$ that $\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}\Big|_V=\frac{1}{T}$

So,$\frac{1}{T}=\frac{1}{T}(U,V)\tag{2}$

Now by reciprocity relation, $\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}\Big|_V=\frac{1}{\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\Big|_V}$
Thus, $\frac{1}{T}(U,V)=\frac{1}{T(S,V)}$

If we have $T(S,V)$ and take reciprocal of it then we have a function of $(U,V)$.
I find this to be strange, like why does this happen?
Taking reciprocal of a function changes the domain set of function?

Please clarify the doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is a diffeomorphism, then the derivative of its inverse is given by :
$$(f^{-1})' = \frac{1}{f'\circ f^{-1}}\tag{1}$$

In your case, you have :
$$\left.\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right|_V(S,V) = T(S,V)$$

and you define the inverse function $S(U,V)$. Then, equation $(1)$ gives you :
$$\left.\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}\right|_V(U,V) = \frac{1}{T(U(S,V),V)}$$
and for practicality, you can define a *new* function $T_2(S,V) = T(U(S,V),V)$.